# How to fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mainpage' ' when starting gunicorn?

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

Well, i'm trying to start `$ sudo docker-compose -f prod.yml up`, and receive an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mainpage'` when Gunicorn starts gis workers.

The path to my wsgi.py is right, it was my last error :D, an i've fixed it.

Well i set my wsgi path right.

I've tried to run it through `manage.py runserver` and it works well.
I've tried to run it through `manage.py runserver` outside the docker and it works well.

this is my project structure:

```
IRM
├── app
│   ├── backend
│   │   ├── api
│   │   ├── combinator
│   │   ├── crowler
│   │   ├── IRMback
│   │   │        ├── __init__.py
│   │   │        ├── settings.py
│   │   │        ├── urls.py
│   │   │        ├── views.py
│   │   │        ├── wsgi.py
│   │   ├── mainpage
│   │   ├── manage.py
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── frontend
│   │     └── ...
│   requirements
│   ├── base.txt
│   ├── local.txt
│   └── prod.txt
│   docker
│   ├── local
│             └── Dockerfile
│   ├── prod
│              └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
└── prod.yml
```

this is my `prod.yml`

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  pgdata:
services: 
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/prod/python/Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - ./app:/app
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    command: gunicorn -w 4 IRMback.IRMback.wsgi.application
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASS: admin
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
```

this is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY app /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements/prod.txt
```

at least, it's part of my settings.py which is relevant to my problem in my opinion:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'corsheaders',

    'mainpage',
    'combinator'
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'IRMback.wsgi.application'
```

Until i wrote this path to my wsgi ( `IRMback.IRMback.wsgi.application`in `prod.yml`), it was an exception ``` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IRMback'``(or IRMback.IRMback) ``` depending on path i've tried.

I except it's running without exceptions ofc.

Should i add wsgi.py in all of my apps or what? Where can i read about it?
The long-time google-searching of Exception text wasn't bring any results.

Comment: For Django projects, your working directory should always be the directory where **manage.py** is located. Everything follows from there. Your gunicorn command should be launching `IRMBack.wgsi:application` I don't understand why your have `IRMBack.IRMBack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be a mixture of `IRMback` and `backend` which is a bit confusing.

In the Dockerfile, try setting `WORKDIR /app/backend`. Then remove one `IRMback` from the gunicorn command:

```
gunicorn -w 4 IRMback.wsgi.application
```

This should allow the module located at `/app/backend/mainpage` to be imported as `mainpage`.